# Variable from pyqt5 file to another .py file

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to figure out ways to share variable define inside a method which is inside a class to a different .py file. The exact problem is, I am trying to check if the checkedbox is tick and depending on the state, it can either return a bool or an integer to a different python file. Could somebody help me with this issue?

gui.py

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    #code.....
    self.f_obj = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self) 
    self.f_obj.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 120, 81, 20)) 
    self.f_obj.stateChanged.connect(self.obj)

def obj(self, checked):
    if checked:
        val = True
    else:
        val = False
    self.value = val

def ret(self):
    return value
```

file.py

get the value return by ret function in the file.py

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have included basic code @S.Nick

Answer (score 0):

This seems closer to a bit of misunderstanding with python/ general coding, rather than pyqt specifically. I'll try to clear it up with general coding examples and hopefully that will help.

Say we had two files: `A.py` and `B.py`. `A.py` contains the class `foo` and `B.py` contains `fi`. If `fi` needs access to a method or property of `foo`, it needs a reference to a `foo` object.

A.py:

```
class foo():
    def get_something(self):
        return self.something
```

B.py:

```
class fi():
    def __init__(self, foo_object):
        self.foo_object = foo_object

    def do_something(self):
        self.foo_object.get_something()
```

As you can see, `fi` just needs a reference to the initialized `foo` object in order to call a function that `foo` has.

However, you mention this as a part of sending information from the main window to another class, so this is not the best method. The main window (`foo`) should have a reference to the other class (`fi`) and when the `ret` function in your example is called, the main window should use its reference to the other class to call a setter function of some kind.

I hope this clears this up, however, if you are unsure how exactly importing works (what you would use to initialize a class from another file), I'd recommend trying to research that instead.
Here is a [Beginner's Python Tutorial on importing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Importing_Modules) that I found on a quick google.

Comment: I am still confused. Can classes return values ?

Comment: I think you are looking for calling a function of a class to get a value. And the answer is that the functions you call on an object can return something. For example:
```
foo = [1, 2]
```
Here `foo` is a list object., that is to say, an instance of the list class. Lists have several functions, such as `pop` which removes and returns the last value of the list.

Honestly though, if you are looking for more information on basic class behavior, you may be better served either making separate questions or finding basic class tutorials and examples  on google.

Comment: You are right @Nicholas and let me reframe the question again. I would like get the state of the ckeckbox in another file for further calculation. lets suppose if i tick the checkbox, I should ether get a bool or a  specific int and will be used in another file. Similarly, if the checkbox is untick . Can anyone suggest a good way to do it